# line-height & font-size relationship

Tags: html, css

This is difficult for me to put right but let me try.

I have horizontal `ul li a` menu:

***Please note that I have omitted some CSS that keep it simple***

```
<ul>
    <li class='featuring'><a href='#'>Whatever</a></li>
    <li class='empty-item'></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Item2</a></li>
    ...
</ul> 

ul li a{
    line-height: 2.4em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    ...
}
ul li.empty-item{
    border-top: 1.7em solid white;
    border-bottom: 1.7em solid white;
    border-left: 1em solid #240B3B;
}
```

Above code gives this:
[image: nav-menu]

Which is great except I wanna change that kindle font-size so I add:

```
ul li.featuring a{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    ...
}
```

And unwanted distortion appears:

[image: nav-menu2]

I suppose that I don't understand line-height property well enough? I though that after changing `ul li.featuring a` font size container size would stay same and only font size inside target element would change but instead element's height scales while leaving rest of the menu items in same proportion and out of sync.
What I thought is that line-height(3.4em) and font-size(1.4em) difference(2em) is cut in half and distributed evenly which would mean that no container height would change???

Hope it is clear.

Thank you.

Comment: Should that be a horizontal menu?

Comment: Are you defining margins and paddings? It's not listed here, but maybe you've hidden this part of css. Without taking control of margins and paddings you won't do it precisely.

Comment: There’s little connection with the code snippet and the screen shot. In particular, that Kindle thing seems to be an image, and this affects things. Please post a sufficient amount of markup and CSS code, preferably in jsfiddle or otherwise easy to check out.

Comment: How can Kindle be an image if I am changing it's font size? That arrow effect is pure CSS. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was certain you'd have an answer by now, but since no one's jumping all over this I'll give it a shot.

It's not so much an issue with `line-height` as it is an issue with relative VS absolute units of measurement.

`em` is a relative unit of measurement, based on the font size. When you increase the font size, you increase all the property values that are measured in `em`, such as your `line-height` here.

- Original: http://jsfiddle.net/MWuHL/
- With your added CSS (shows the extra space): http://jsfiddle.net/MWuHL/1/

Using an absolute unit like `px` will not change based on font size:

- With your added CSS, but measuring line-height in `px`: http://jsfiddle.net/MWuHL/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for a quality answer. Appreciate that. All best!